# IE9 - adding and removing DOM element breaks parent keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, internet-explorer, jquery-events

We're building a rather complex UI control (a datagrid in fact) and are dynamically adding/removing nodes from the DOM tree as users scroll the grid (and trying to do it with as high perf as possible).

We've noticed in IE9 & IE10 that when we add/remove child elements from a node, it stops firing its keydown event:

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/T2Lt8/13/

You can see that after just two or so keydown events, the parent stops firing. However, if I uncomment the `$(child).focus()` line in the keydown handler - it all works.

What is going on, and is this the best hack to work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the example a while, I found the following things:

1. If you add `child.style.border = "1px solid red";` you see that a second child is created as the first one is not removed. This is due to there being [whitespace in the parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.firstChild?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=firstChild).
2. The child is bigger than the parent. If you make the parent 150px by 150px and just click the parent and not the child, the key events work correctly and repeatedly. It seems IE9 does keep the binding.
3. If the child is something "opaque" like a `textarea`, it seems to make Firefox behave like the behavior we saw for IE9.